# weak* convergence in Sobolev space

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, weak-convergence

Consider $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^{N}$, open and bounded. If $u_{n} \rightharpoonup^{*} u$ in $W^{1,\infty}_{0}(\Omega)$, then does it follow that $u_{n} \rightharpoonup^{*} u$ in $W^{1,\infty}(\Omega)$?

Thanks.

Comment: What is your definition for $W_0^{1,\infty}(\Omega)$?

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me that since $W_0^{1,\infty}\subset W^{1,\infty}$, we have $(W^{1,\infty})^*\subset (W_0^{1,\infty})^*$. Therefore, if $u_n\to u$ weak star in $W_0^{1,\infty}$, it automatically weak star with respect to $W^{1,\infty}$.

Comment: What is your definition for $W_0^{1,\infty}(\Omega)$?

Comment: @Tomás with trace 0?

Comment: I see. I'm asking, because it is usual to define it, as the weak star closure of $C_0^1(\Omega)$ in $W^{1,\infty}(\Omega)$.

Comment: @Tomás of course you are right. I think we discussed this before right?:)

Comment: Yes. Anyway, how do you identify bounded linear functionals defined in $W^{1,\infty}$ with bounded linear functional defined in $W_0^{1,\infty}$?

Comment: How can one talk about weak star convergence in $W_0^{1,\infty}$ without knowing its pre dual?

Comment: @Tomás you are absolutely right. I was ignoring this part before. Will work on this tonight.

Comment: I was just wondering. We need to fomarlize it in the correct way.